# fetch_field() function in Zend to get metadata result set

Tags: php, postgresql, metadata, zend-framework

In PHP, there is `fetch_field()` function to get metadata from a result set. 
[php-manual-mysql_fetch_field](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-field.php)

Is there a similar function in Zend Framework,.?

but, in this case I'm using PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 1):

`Zend_Db_Table` has a method `info()` which returns an array with metadata of the table.

Example:
    $table = new Zend_Db_Table(array('name' => 'table_name'));
    $tableInfo = $table->info();

For more information, go to http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.table.html#zend.db.table.info